# JQuantlib Logger configuration

Tags: java, jquantlib

I am trying to use `JQuantLib`, but I'm getting too many system.err messages being thrown at console. Would someone please suggest on how a `Log4J` logger could be configured in `JQuantLib`, so all library messages are routed to the configured logger instead of console.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, Luigi, one of the major contributor to QuantLib corrected my question, but missed adding a line of text on how to get this working :( `

Comment: Any recommendations on how to get this working or any documentation for this or any suggestions on which JQuantLib Code file needs to be looked into or any suggestion on where i could find the code architecture of JQuantlib on net?

Comment: @chris did you find a solution?

Comment: @ps0604, DIdnt find any solution to this. stopped looking.

Comment: Kris, I switched to the quantlib-python library, calling functions with http microservices. It works perfectly.